# Creating Predictive Regression Equations Using MRFs in MGCV Package RStudio

Tags: r, mgcv

I am working with historic nutrient concentration data from a number of monitoring stations along with corresponding historic flows. I am trying to write predictive regression equations for estimating concentrations at stations that are now closed. I have watched a number of tutorials on the MGCV package and have decided that markov random fields would be appropriate for what I am doing. I was not sure how to select certain parameters to build a regression from a larger data frame, so I have tailored data frames to only contain the information needed for each stations regression. Here is an example for Station C9:

`C9_TP_Reg`:

```
Station, Date.x, Month, Year, Day, TP, SWP, CVP
D19, 1975-1-07, 1, 1975, 7, 0.1, 3593, 1071
C9, 1975-1-22, 1, 1975, 22, 0.16, 1914, 3483
D28A, 1975-02-03, 2, 1975, 3, 0.11, 2360, 4506
...
```

This is a large Data set that spans for several years...

I attempted to write my regression using the following code:

```
TP_C9 <- gam(TP ~ s(Date.x) + s(Station,bs="mrf",xt=list(nb=nb)) + 
             s(SWP) + s(CVP), data=C9_TP_reg)
```

I got this error:

> ```
> Error in names(dat) <- object$term : 'names' attribute [1] must be 
> the same length as the vector [0]
> ```

If anyone can help me I would be very thankful. I have spent hours watching tutorials on the MGCV package and can't get this to work.

I am assuming that if I just fit for all stations I can rework the equation and solve for C9 to estimate future concentrations...

Comment: Is `Station` coded as a factor?

Comment: I just looked and my stations are currently coded as characters. I will change them to factors. I just started looking into a package called baytrends that applies GAMs to water quality constituents. I am considering trying to follow a format simmilar to this:

Comment: I started looking into a package called baytrends that applies GAMs to water quality constituents. I am considering trying to follow a format similar to this: gam2_flwsal: gam(y ∼ cyear + s(cyear, k = gamK1) + s (doy,bs = 'cc') + ti(cyear,doy,bs = c('tp','cc')) + s (flw_sal,k = gamK2) + ti(flw_sal,doy,bs = c('tp','cc')) + ti(flw_sal, cyear,bs = c('tp','tp')) + ti(flw_sal,doy,cyear, bs = c('tp','cc','tp')), knots=list(doy=c(1,366)),select=TRUE)
Where gamK1=c(10,1/3), gamK2=c(10,2/3), cyear= zero centered date in decimal form, and doy=day of year as a numeric (366 to account for leap years).

Comment: The study I am reading uses this GAM to evaluate trends at each station, whereas I am trying to write equations for historic stations that may be described by the nutrient concentrations at surrounding stations that are still monitoring along with flow conditions. I am attempting to write these equations for nitrogen and phosphorous species, which go through biogeochemical transformation. Equations for nitrogen species were written by a colleague of mine in the past using isotopic data for delta 15 N, although her equations only apply for June-October.

Comment: The hope is that this code can help provide background needed for establishing a TMDL and help reduce eutrophic conditions and improve water quality. If you have any advice or resources you can suggest I would be incredibly grateful.

Comment: After changing Station to a factor I get this error: Error in names(dat) <- object$term : 'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]

Answer (score 0):

You could include the as.factor function in the formula:

```
s(as.factor(Station),bs="mrf",xt=list(nb=objectpolygon))
```

And give your nb object the names of the shape file you are using, like

```
names(objectpolygon) <- attr(objectpolygon, "station.id")
```

There was a question I read recently about this problem. I will add the link when I find it. Perhaps the problem is there. I am new myself to mgcv and trying to fit a model with mrf smoothing.
By the way, I created my *objectpolygon* with function `poly2nb` from **spdep** package.